# Enzyme not returning the correct children for a newly defined component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm expecting the following test to pass:

```
const Foo = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);

describe('<Foo />', function () {
  it('always renders a <div />', function () {
    const foo = mount(
      <Foo>
        <div className="foo" />
      </Foo>
    );

    expect(foo.children().html()).to.equal('<div class="foo"></div>');
  });
});
```

However, the above would give me:

```
AssertionError: expected '<div><div class="foo"></div></div>' to equal '<div class="foo"></div>'
```

### Temporary fix

I found that I can simply chain two `children()` calls to make this work:

```
describe('<Foo />', function () {
  it('always renders a <div />', function () {
    const foo = mount(
      <Foo>
        <div className="foo" />
      </Foo>
    );

    expect(foo.children().children().html()).to.equal('<div class="foo"></div>');
  });
});
```

### Inconsistency

If I just use a normal `div` instead of the `Foo` component to wrap the inner `div`, I'll get the right result. That is,

```
describe('<Foo />', function () {
  it('always renders a <div />', function () {
    const foo = mount(
      <div>
        <div className="foo" />
      </div>
    );

    expect(foo.children().html()).to.equal('<div class="foo"></div>');
  });
});
```

Furthermore, I found that `foo.children().html()` returns exactly the same string as `foo.html()`. Hence the following `expect` would pass:

```
expect(foo.html()).to.equal(foo.children().html());
```

### Question

If that's the expected behaviour, why?
Is there a neater way to get the children than just to chain it twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I haven't received an answer or gathered enough views on this question, I've logged an [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1417) on the repository and "ljharb" has given me the answer:

> This is intentional. When you mount a component, you get that component - you need .children() to get at the thing it renders.